# How to catch in trigger what changes caused by foreign key integrity in Postgres PL/PGSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

Case for example: table `"user"` has fields `id` and `total`, table `purchase` has `user_id` (as foreign key to `"user".id` with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`) and `cost`.

I would like to auto-update `total` on any changes in `purchase` (so `total` will always be equal to the sum of all purchases for a given user). I do it via row trigger `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON purchase`. Technically it is possible that `purchase.user_id` is changed, and there are two cases:

1. This change is caused by changing `"user".id` from one user to another. In this case I decrease `total` for the old user and increase it for the new user.
2. This change is caused by changing `id` in table `"user"` (and the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` changes the corresponding `user_id`s in `purchase`). In this case I should do nothing by my own trigger.

How to catch second case in trigger? There is the analogous question about catching a deletion in `purchase` caused by a deletion in `"user"`.

Comment: i'd calculate the total in a view except you have a very very good reason not to do it.

Comment: Coerced case is simplified. In reality updates in "purchase" occur infrequently (may be up to 10 per month per user), but requests to "total" may happened at least 1 per second and it should be up-to-date. And there are a lot of records in "purchase". So view may be to slow for me.

Comment: Best solution: **Don't update primary keys**. If you need an editable ID, put it in a separate `UNIQUE` column. Many things become much simpler when you have stable row identifiers (especially when it comes to writing triggers).

Comment: In really I do not update primary keys. But I don't want to rely on smth like "There is no problem because this case will never happen." - If it is technically possible than sometimes it will happen.

Comment: @Unsacrificed: Then make it impossible. Revoke `UPDATE` permission on the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of a cascading `DELETE` there is nothing to do; the `UPDATE`s from the trigger on `purchase` would just do nothing as the matching row in `"user"` does not exist any more.

To handle an `UPDATE` of `"user".id`, you could create a trigger `BEFORE UPDATE ON "user"` that sets `NEW.total` to 0. Then after the trigger on `purchase` has run, the value will be the same as before.

Comment: About `UPDATE`: looks like it should work. But bad news is what it cause unneeded recalculation of total. And second - trigger should silently ignore error about subtraction total for "original" (really the same) user.
About cascading `DELETE`: I think it is not very clean way.
Whats happened if request1 try to `DELETE` row from purchase and request2 (near simultaneous) try to `UPDATE` id for appropriate user? If my trigger on `purchase` does not find appropriate `user` it is problem of concurrency (so, recalculation required) or it is just deletion of user?

Comment: Concerning unneeded recalculation of `total`: If you update primary keys so often that this is a problem, you're doing something wrong. Primary keys should not change. You cannot tell from within the trigger if the `UPDATE` was caused by a cascading foreign key or not. There is no problem in the `DELETE` case because until the transaction (which contains at least the statement and its triggers) is finished, a lock will block concurrent `INSERT`s of the same primary key.